# Рефакторинг метода приведения строки к обьекту

Tags: c#, json, рефакторинг

Есть сервер который в случае неверного запроса возвращает десериализованную `JSON` строку, представляющюу обьект типа `EXCEPTION`. В зависимости от типа ошибки обьект может иметь совершенно различную структуру от простого :

```
public class simpleException
{
    public string Reason {get;set;}
    public string Controller {get;set;}
}
```

Что бы обработать полученный ответ и понять что именно за исключение произошло есть метод :

```
try 
{
    var Err = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<simpleException>(responsedBodyStr);
}
catch (JsonSerializationException)
{
    try 
    {
        var Err = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TrsException>(responsedBodyStr);
    } 
    catch(JsonSerializationException)
    {
        try {....
    }
}
```

Уровней вложений  `try-catch` гораздо больше и они превращаются в ужасный спагетти код. Собственно вопрос - если вы сталкивались с подобными ситуациями то поделитесь советом как улучшить код ?

upd Строку исключения получаю так :

```
catch (WebException ex)
{
    ExcStr= new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd(),
```

Comment: _В зависимости от типа ошибки обьект может иметь совершенно различную структуру_ - тип ошибки где-то указывается?

Comment: @Grundy в json нет, только в `WebException` можно посмотреть статус код и `Status Description`

Comment: *Есть сервер который в случае неверного запроса возвращает десериализованную JSON строку, представляющюу обьект типа EXCEPTION* — не совсем понятно. К вам приходит объект типа `Exception`?

Comment: @АндрейNOP сервер на `asp` поля обьекта сериализуются в json строку и возвращается с ответом сервера.

Comment: Хорошо, а что значит *JSON строку, представляющюу обьект типа EXCEPTION*? Это какой-то базовый класс? Мы можем десериализовать в него?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как первое приближение, разверните вложенность в цикл. Наивный пример:

Процессор-композит собирает обработчики для исключения и прогоняет их

```
public class ExceptionProc
{
    private List<Func<string, bool>> _processors = new List<System.Func<string, bool>>();

    public void AddProc(Func<string, bool> proc)
    {           
        _processors.Add(proc);
    }

    public bool ProcessException(string input)
    {
        foreach(var proc in _processors)
        {
            try
            {
                if (proc(input)) return true;
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                /// logging
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Как использовать

```
var processor = new ExceptionProc();
processor.AddProc((responsedBodyStr) => 
    {
        var Err = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<simpleException>(responsedBodyStr);
        // .. do stuff
        return true;
    });

processor.AddProc((responsedBodyStr) =>
    {
        var Err = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TrsException>(responsedBodyStr);
        // .. do stuff
        return true;
    });

if (!processor.ProcessException(someString)) ;
{
    // logging fail
}
```

В итоге добавление обработчика стало делом элементарным. 
Try-catch можно запихнуть в обработчик, обработчик можно сделать классом с методом CanProcess, ну и много чего ещё можно сделать, зависит от задачи

Comment: А не существует ли способа передавать в `< >` тип динамически ? по сути в `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TrsException>` всегда меняется только тип исключения.

Comment: @Сергей конечно существует. Пишите обобщенную функцию, например `bool MyFunction<T>(string response) { JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response); ..... }` Вызываете как `MyFunction<MyException>(response);`

Answer (score 0):

*У JSON-объекта должен быть какой-нибудь код ошибки, либо по HTTP-коду должна быть дифференциация, либо наследование. Очень уж бестолково пытаться так угадывать, тем более через полный парсинг и исключения.*

Решением может быть [LINQ to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm):

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(@"{
  'CPU': 'Intel',
  'Drives': [
    'DVD read/writer',
    '500 gigabyte hard drive'
  ]
}");

string cpu = (string)o["CPU"];
// Intel

string firstDrive = (string)o["Drives"][0];
// DVD read/writer

IList<string> allDrives = o["Drives"].Select(t => (string)t).ToList();
// DVD read/writer
// 500 gigabyte hard drive
```